# Average cells within a range updates automatically, based on row values

Tags: excel

I have attached a sample file below. Can you help?

I'm looking for a formula to show the calculated average in cell B1 of the included sample, were the range (currently B2:B3) updates automatically when a new row is inserted at row 4 and the value 1.3 is shown in cell A4.

The range of the average formula in Cell B1, should update to show B2:B4... etc and continue to automatically update as new rows are added and additional numbers are added (1.4 in cell A5, average range updates to B2:B5, 1.5 in A6, average range updates to B2:B6 and so on...)

Thanks in advance for your help

[Sample](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsC7wzkdT-On5ksltvSqpRkVjtgm)

Comment: Sample input and output are welcome.

Comment: Please note that "I need a little support" [isn't really a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Can you be more specific? Please also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @EJoshuaS appreciate its not a question, but i was trying trying to convey i'm not a complete novice. Will try harder in future.

Comment: @SangbokLee i have added a link to the book in the request for help. Basically i'm looking for the formula in cell B1 to recalculate the range B2:B3 if a new row is inserted and 1.3 is added in cell A4.

Comment: Edit your question according to the sample file, then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @SangbokLee i have updated my question, I hope this is a bit clearer and more specific

Comment: Why not simply set `B1` to `=average(b2:b999)`?

Comment: Because I want to average the only the rows that contain a 1.xx prefix. I plan to repeat the calculation for 2.xx and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I got what you mean. But your sheet looks not very efficient. Why not set `A1` to `1`, and `A2` to `=A1+0.1`, and so on? For now `A` column has very long formulae which is hard to read.

Anyway... to use `averageif()` on `1.1`, `2.1`, etc, it'll be easier to make `A` column to text. So add another column(say `C`) and set `C1` to `=text(a1, "#")` and drag down. Now that `C1` is text, you can use `averageif()` with wildcard(`*`). set `B1` like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(C2:C99, C1&"*", B2:B99)
```

Of course, you should copy `B1` and paste onto `B4` and so on manually. Sample Excel file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/usy4xks06z1tz4d/43122560.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Doing A+0.1 will mean when the row number gets to 1.9 it will jump to 2.0 whereas I would like it to keep counting as 1.9, 1.10,1.11 etc

Comment: Then you can seperate A column into two columns. For example for `1.12`, you can set A to `1` and B to `12`. If I were you I'd do like that. Also that way, `averageif`, `countif`, and EVERYTHING will be much more easier.